# Custom filter not refreshing on interval in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have created custom filter in Snowflake Dashboard using options via **Query**, Set the refresh frequency as **refresh hourly**. But the issue is the filter is not adding new values that are coming in the table used in Query.

Did someone faced this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Snowflake team this is an open bug and scheduled to be fixed in coming sprints.